# Why syntax highlighting is visible only on preview page?

Tags: support, tags

**Preview on edit question**

[image: Edit Preview]

**Question Page**

[image: Question Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax highlighting on final questions is performed based on the tags on the question.

The community moderators determine which tags have syntax highlighting and which do not; this setting is editable for community moderators at the bottom of the tag info page.