# Syntax-highlight activation for tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Dear Mods,

Taken in mind the following meta [answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/why-syntax-highlighting-is-visible-only-on-preview-page/467#467), and [some](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/terminal-ps1-and-colors) [examples](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11243/automatically-delete-a-folder-daily) [without](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10666/why-setting-image-as-its-own-icon-with-sips-result-a-blurred-icon-are-there-any) [syntax](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/i-messed-up-my-bash-configuration-on-mac)-[highlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11016/open-new-terminal-tab-in-the-same-directory-with-the-active-tab), please enable it for the following tags:

- applescript
- launchd (for their plist/xml files)
- terminal
- script
- bash
- shell

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting has been turned on for the site.  The community moderators will be able to set the language for a tag on its info page.

Answer (score 0):

I've added syntax highlight for the tags you mentioned. It may take a little time to figure out which language to use for AppleScript, and which language is most common for 'script'.

Feel free to comment if there's a problem.

Comment: I suggest turning it on for plist. Examples: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10404/cant-quit-app-launched-through-launchd has it due to script. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8166/running-a-command-whenever-mac-boots-up-with-launchctl-plist doesn't. (Funny, that they used launchctl instead of launchd...)

Comment: @Jason Done. [chars]